# Not able to save edited layer connected via PostGIS in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, editing

I have project and I was doing editing layers in `QGIS`. These layers are connected in QGIS via `PostGIS`. One layer of the four layers was saved correctly but other layers gave me error message.

Error message looks like this:

> ERROR: 15 geometries not changed. ERROR:  LineString must have at least
>   two points CONTEXT:  SQL function "st_geomfromwkb" statement 1

Answer (score 1):

The error message seems to be clear. Are you sure, that you're trying to save lines to fields with type LineString?

Comment: Sometimes I received the same error, it happens when you delete a vertex of a line with only two vertex, or that have three vertex but 2 of them overlapping. I don't know why qgis allows you to delete a vertex of a line like that but it happens... If you get out of the edit mode without saving, you not lose your edited geometries (another strange thing) just the one with the error.

Comment: @Fatal Yeah you are right. I did not lose my edited lines and polygons. I did not really understand why it happens in Qgis as well as you. Anyway then i have continued in editing and i didn't get this error message anymore.